# Insufficient memory for the JRE in Spark on CentOS7 within VMWare

Tags: hadoop, memory, apache-spark, centos7

I am new to spark and am trying to run spark on my hadoop node CentOS7, which is on a vmware: 2GB RAM, 20GB disk, 1CPU

I am receiving this error message:

```
[root@xie1 spark]# bin/spark-shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 716177408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 716177408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/spark/hs_err_pid79417.log
```

After some googling I checked the mem below:

```
[root@xie1 spark]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1868688 kB
MemFree:           76428 kB
MemAvailable:      80840 kB
Buffers:              68 kB
Cached:            92172 kB
SwapCached:       189260 kB
Active:          1158888 kB
Inactive:         426036 kB
Active(anon):    1108308 kB
Inactive(anon):   389960 kB
Active(file):      50580 kB
Inactive(file):    36076 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:         282684 kB
Dirty:                76 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1303360 kB
Mapped:            42176 kB
Shmem:              5596 kB
Slab:              95580 kB
SReclaimable:      34792 kB
SUnreclaim:        60788 kB
KernelStack:       19616 kB
PageTables:        32960 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3031492 kB
Committed_AS:    6290644 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      173440 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359561216 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    319488 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      102272 kB
DirectMap2M:     1994752 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

what's the meaning of "**VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB**", it exceeds the disk size I allocate to the VM which is 20G. Is VmallocTotal some where that can be adjusted? I am guessing the spark is asking for more resource, based on my current allocation of VM, what can I do? and how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your memory seems really limited. try to modify configuration of memory allocation.